# Displaying different blocks on different pages?

Tags: php, content-management-system, drupal-7

I want to be able to display different blocks (on the side panels) for different pages.

For example, if they are on the home page, they may see the login and search on the left side panel, but if they go to the about us page, I want those 2 to be gone, and just display a different block.

Can this be done in Drupal 7?

Comment: Is doing this with CSS an option for you?

Comment: @hakre How would you do this with just CSS? If we do go that path, I think there'd have to be some PHP intervention in order to determine which page you were on and what needs to be displayed. But truthfully, I was hoping there'd be an easier way to do this - is there nothing in the admin area that allows you to specify different blocks for different pages? At the moment you can only specify the blocks site-wide, which isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7, you administer blocks at /admin/structure/block. There's a lot of flexibility in how the block is displayed, including where and when.

Comment: Can you please explain how this can be done? Where exactly in the blocks administration area can I specify which pages a block should display on?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. For anyone else searching, it's at Structure -> Blocks -> Configure (link next to block you want to modify) -> Specify the pages you want to restrict it to on the bottom.